# gganimate animation rendering twice in flexdashboard

Tags: r, flexdashboard, gganimate

I'm creating video animations using gganimate and I want to include these in a flexdashboard. The issue is that the animations are rendering twice when I knit the flexdashboard. The first animation is just as expected, but next to it is the same animation again, though smaller. Would anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent the second rendering? Example code below (you'll need to remove the "#" when pasting into an rmarkdown doc). Thanks.

[image: gganimate duplicated rendering]

````
#---
title: "Animated charts MRE"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
#---

#```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)


p <-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) 

animate(p, renderer = av_renderer())
#```
````

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue. Works well with gifski and magick renderers but those don't have pause buttons.